# LWJGL Text cusotom rendering crashing with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, text, rendering, lwjgl

So I was writing my own font/text renderer for an LWJGL code, but It has these weird lag spikes when running and the letters randomly change into another letter before reverting to what it was before, does anyone know what is wrong with my code.

```
public class RenderFont extends EntityBase{

    String text;
    String Font;
    String filename;
    Texture string[] = new Texture[200];
    int TextureStringLen = 0;
    public RenderFont(int x, int y, int size, String text, String font) {

        super(x, y, size, size*2, null);
        this.Text=text;
        this.Font=font;
        this.GenerateTextureArray();


    }

    public RenderFont(int x, int y, int size,String text) {

        super(x, y, size, size*2, null);
        this.Text=text;
        this.Font="default";
        this.GenerateTextureArray();

    }

    public void GenerateTextureArray(){

        this.TextureStringLen=0;
        for(int i = 0;
                i<this.Text.length();
                i++){





                if(Character.isUpperCase(this.Text.substring(i,i+1).charAt(0))){

                    this.filename = "uppercase/"+Text.substring(i,i+1);

                }else{

                    if(Character.isLowerCase(this.Text.substring(i, i+1).charAt(0))){

                        this.filename = "lowercase/" + Text.substring(i,i+1);

                    }else{

                        this.filename = "other/" + Text.substring(i, i+1);

                    }

                }

                if(this.Text.substring(i,i+1).equals(":")){

                    this.filename = "other/colon";

                }

                try {

                    this.string[i] = AssortedTools.GetTextureError(this.Font+"/"+this.filename);

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    this.string[i] = AssortedTools.GetTexture("null");

                }

                this.TextureStringLen+=1;

            }




    }

    @Override
    public void Draw(){

        for(int i = 0;
            i<this.TextureStringLen;
            i++){


            this.string[i].bind();
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(0,0);
                glVertex2d(this.topleftx+(i*this.Width*0.7),this.toplefty);
                glTexCoord2f(1,0);
                glVertex2d(this.toprightx+(i*this.Width*0.7),this.toprighty);
                glTexCoord2f(1,1);
                glVertex2d(this.bottomleftx+(i*this.Width*0.7),this.bottomlefty);
                glTexCoord2f(0,1);
                glVertex2d(this.bottomrightx+(i*this.Width*0.7),this.bottomrighty);
            glEnd();

        }

    }



    public void SetText(String str){

        this.Text = str;
        this.GenerateTextureArray();
    }

    public String GetText(){

        return this.Text;

    }

    public void SetFont(String str){

        this.Font = str;
        this.GenerateTextureArray();
    }

    public String GetFont(){

        return this.Font;

    }

}
```

and the getTextureError function is

```
public static Texture GetTextureError(String name) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    return TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG",new FileInputStream(new File("res/"+name+".png")));


}
```

the error log is

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x5369a540, pid=9372, tid=1456
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [nvoglv32.DLL+0xafa540]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00ddc400):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1456, stack(0x00930000,0x00980000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x1fc40048, EBX=0x1b740020, ECX=0x02448000, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x0097f300, EBP=0x0097f6b4, ESI=0x1ed00048, EDI=0x1a630000
EIP=0x5369a540, EFLAGS=0x00010297

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0097f300)
0x0097f300:   1a68d0ec 1ed00048 1a630000 0097f348
0x0097f310:   0097f36c 0097f370 0097f320 0005174c
0x0097f320:   00000000 0097f378 77c6ed75 0097f348
0x0097f330:   0097f36c 0097f370 0097f368 0097f468
0x0097f340:   0097f494 0097f484 00000018 00000003
0x0097f350:   00000000 00000002 00000003 00000002
0x0097f360:   00000001 35277c24 00000000 0005174c
0x0097f370:   000007a0 0097f384 0097f434 77c6f3df 

Instructions: (pc=0x5369a540)
0x5369a520:   fc de 05 00 8b 97 f4 de 05 00 83 e8 2c 89 45 08
0x5369a530:   89 55 14 3b d0 0f 87 27 01 00 00 eb 03 8d 49 00
0x5369a540:   f6 02 80 0f 84 aa 00 00 00 8b 72 24 0f b7 4e 28
0x5369a550:   0f bc c1 89 4d f8 89 45 ec 89 45 c8 85 c9 0f 84 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x1fc40048 is an unknown value
EBX=0x1b740020 is an unknown value
ECX=0x02448000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x0097f300 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00ddc400
EBP=0x0097f6b4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00ddc400
ESI=0x1ed00048 is an unknown value
EDI=0x1a630000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00930000,0x00980000],  sp=0x0097f300,  free space=316k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [nvoglv32.DLL+0xafa540]
C  [nvoglv32.DLL+0xa972fa]
C  [nvoglv32.DLL+0xaa171c]
C  [nvoglv32.DLL+0xa973fd]
C  [nvoglv32.DLL+0xa9002e]
C  [lwjgl.dll+0xab2e]
J  org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureImpl.bind()V
j  main.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x13f1fa]
V  [jvm.dll+0x202aee]
V  [jvm.dll+0x13f27d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xc9945]
V  [jvm.dll+0xd45e7]
C  [javaw.exe+0x2070]
C  [javaw.exe+0xa5b1]
C  [javaw.exe+0xa63b]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x1338a]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39f72]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x39f45]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.nglBindTexture(IIJ)V
J  org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureImpl.bind()V
J  entities.EntityBase.Draw()V
J  entityHandlers.EntityHandler.Draw()V
j  main.Main.<init>()V+144
j  main.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x1c5efc00 JavaThread "LWJGL Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10796, stack(0x1f280000,0x1f2d0000)]
  0x18844000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11044, stack(0x00980000,0x009d0000)]
  0x1883e800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10204, stack(0x01220000,0x01270000)]
  0x1883d400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=840, stack(0x012b0000,0x01300000)]
  0x1883a400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10716, stack(0x01330000,0x01380000)]
  0x00edf800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9632, stack(0x002d0000,0x00320000)]
  0x00eda800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9880, stack(0x00d60000,0x00db0000)]
=>0x00ddc400 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1456, stack(0x00930000,0x00980000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00ed8800 VMThread [stack: 0x011d0000,0x01220000] [id=760]
  0x18856800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x18d00000,0x18d50000] [id=5292]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 17856K, used 662K [0x047c0000, 0x05b10000, 0x09d10000)
  eden space 15936K,   4% used [0x047c0000, 0x048659a0, 0x05750000)
  from space 1920K,   0% used [0x05750000, 0x05750000, 0x05930000)
  to   space 1920K,   0% used [0x05930000, 0x05930000, 0x05b10000)
 tenured generation   total 39484K, used 23688K [0x09d10000, 0x0c39f000, 0x147c0000)
   the space 39484K,  59% used [0x09d10000, 0x0b4323e8, 0x0b432400, 0x0c39f000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3299K [0x147c0000, 0x153c0000, 0x187c0000)
   the space 12288K,  26% used [0x147c0000, 0x14af8e78, 0x14af9000, 0x153c0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Card table byte_map: [0x00ee0000,0x00f90000] byte_map_base: 0x00ebc200

Polling page: 0x00190000

Code Cache  [0x027c0000, 0x028f0000, 0x047c0000)
 total_blobs=712 nmethods=504 adapters=145 free_code_cache=31573Kb largest_free_block=32330816

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 39.280 Thread 0x1883e800  499             org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplayPeerInfo::doLockAndInitHandle (1 bytes)
Event: 39.281 Thread 0x1883e800 nmethod 499 0x028e9e08 code [0x028e9f00, 0x028e9f80]
Event: 39.281 Thread 0x1883e800  500             org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplayPeerInfo::doUnlock (1 bytes)
Event: 39.281 Thread 0x1883e800 nmethod 500 0x028e9fc8 code [0x028ea0c0, 0x028ea140]
Event: 43.714 Thread 0x1883e800  501             java.lang.ThreadLocal::get (34 bytes)
Event: 43.714 Thread 0x1883e800 nmethod 501 0x028ea188 code [0x028ea2a0, 0x028ea398]
Event: 46.074 Thread 0x1883e800  502             entities.EntityPlayerMissile::Update (24 bytes)
Event: 46.075 Thread 0x1883e800 nmethod 502 0x028ea4c8 code [0x028ea5c0, 0x028ea67c]
Event: 55.021 Thread 0x1883e800  504             entities.EntityBase::moveX (66 bytes)
Event: 55.021 Thread 0x1883e800 nmethod 504 0x028ea988 code [0x028eaa80, 0x028eab50]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 63.677 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=248 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 14528K, used 13957K [0x047c0000, 0x05780000, 0x09d10000)
  eden space 12928K, 100% used [0x047c0000, 0x05460000, 0x05460000)
  from space 1600K,  64% used [0x05460000, 0x055615d8, 0x055f0000)
  to   space 1600K,   0% used [0x055f0000, 0x055f0000, 0x05780000)
 tenured generation   total 32216K, used 31049K [0x09d10000, 0x0bc86000, 0x147c0000)
   the space 32216K,  96% used [0x09d10000, 0x0bb62750, 0x0bb62800, 0x0bc86000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3301K [0x147c0000, 0x153c0000, 0x187c0000)
   the space 12288K,  26% used [0x147c0000, 0x14af9498, 0x14af9600, 0x153c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 63.682 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=249 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 14528K, used 1038K [0x047c0000, 0x05780000, 0x09d10000)
  eden space 12928K,   0% used [0x047c0000, 0x047c0000, 0x05460000)
  from space 1600K,  64% used [0x055f0000, 0x056f3b28, 0x05780000)
  to   space 1600K,   0% used [0x05460000, 0x05460000, 0x055f0000)
 tenured generation   total 32216K, used 31305K [0x09d10000, 0x0bc86000, 0x147c0000)
   the space 32216K,  97% used [0x09d10000, 0x0bba27f8, 0x0bba2800, 0x0bc86000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3301K [0x147c0000, 0x153c0000, 0x187c0000)
   the space 12288K,  26% used [0x147c0000, 0x14af9498, 0x14af9600, 0x153c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 64.108 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=249 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 14528K, used 13966K [0x047c0000, 0x05780000, 0x09d10000)
  eden space 12928K, 100% used [0x047c0000, 0x05460000, 0x05460000)
  from space 1600K,  64% used [0x055f0000, 0x056f3b28, 0x05780000)
  to   space 1600K,   0% used [0x05460000, 0x05460000, 0x055f0000)
 tenured generation   total 32216K, used 31305K [0x09d10000, 0x0bc86000, 0x147c0000)
   the space 32216K,  97% used [0x09d10000, 0x0bba27f8, 0x0bba2800, 0x0bc86000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3301K [0x147c0000, 0x153c0000, 0x187c0000)
   the space 12288K,  26% used [0x147c0000, 0x14af9498, 0x14af9600, 0x153c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 64.113 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=250 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 14528K, used 1038K [0x047c0000, 0x05780000, 0x09d10000)
  eden space 12928K,   0% used [0x047c0000, 0x047c0000, 0x05460000)
  from space 1600K,  64% used [0x05460000, 0x05563870, 0x055f0000)
  to   space 1600K,   0% used [0x055f0000, 0x055f0000, 0x05780000)
 tenured generation   total 32216K, used 31562K [0x09d10000, 0x0bc86000, 0x147c0000)
   the space 32216K,  97% used [0x09d10000, 0x0bbe2838, 0x0bbe2a00, 0x0bc86000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3301K [0x147c0000, 0x153c0000, 0x187c0000)
   the space 12288K,  26% used [0x147c0000, 0x14af9498, 0x14af9600, 0x153c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 64.615 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=250 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 14528K, used 13966K [0x047c0000, 0x05780000, 0x09d10000)
  eden space 12928K, 100% used [0x047c0000, 0x05460000, 0x05460000)
  from space 1600K,  64% used [0x05460000, 0x05563870, 0x055f0000)
  to   space 1600K,   0% used [0x055f0000, 0x055f0000, 0x05780000)
 tenured generation   total 32216K, used 31562K [0x09d10000, 0x0bc86000, 0x147c0000)
   the space 32216K,  97% used [0x09d10000, 0x0bbe2838, 0x0bbe2a00, 0x0bc86000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3301K [0x147c0000, 0x153c0000, 0x187c0000)
   the space 12288K,  26% used [0x147c0000, 0x14af9498, 0x14af9600, 0x153c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 64.619 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=251 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 14528K, used 1039K [0x047c0000, 0x05780000, 0x09d10000)
  eden space 12928K,   0% used [0x047c0000, 0x047c0000, 0x05460000)
  from space 1600K,  64% used [0x055f0000, 0x056f3d20, 0x05780000)
  to   space 1600K,   0% used [0x05460000, 0x05460000, 0x055f0000)
 tenured generation   total 32216K, used 31818K [0x09d10000, 0x0bc86000, 0x147c0000)
   the space 32216K,  98% used [0x09d10000, 0x0bc22aa0, 0x0bc22c00, 0x0bc86000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3301K [0x147c0000, 0x153c0000, 0x187c0000)
   the space 12288K,  26% used [0x147c0000, 0x14af9498, 0x14af9600, 0x153c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 65.202 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=251 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 14528K, used 13967K [0x047c0000, 0x05780000, 0x09d10000)
  eden space 12928K, 100% used [0x047c0000, 0x05460000, 0x05460000)
  from space 1600K,  64% used [0x055f0000, 0x056f3d20, 0x05780000)
  to   space 1600K,   0% used [0x05460000, 0x05460000, 0x055f0000)
 tenured generation   total 32216K, used 31818K [0x09d10000, 0x0bc86000, 0x147c0000)
   the space 32216K,  98% used [0x09d10000, 0x0bc22aa0, 0x0bc22c00, 0x0bc86000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3301K [0x147c0000, 0x153c0000, 0x187c0000)
   the space 12288K,  26% used [0x147c0000, 0x14af9498, 0x14af9600, 0x153c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 65.207 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=252 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 14528K, used 1029K [0x047c0000, 0x05780000, 0x09d10000)
  eden space 12928K,   0% used [0x047c0000, 0x047c0000, 0x05460000)
  from space 1600K,  64% used [0x05460000, 0x055616a8, 0x055f0000)
  to   space 1600K,   0% used [0x055f0000, 0x055f0000, 0x05780000)
 tenured generation   total 32216K, used 32074K [0x09d10000, 0x0bc86000, 0x147c0000)
   the space 32216K,  99% used [0x09d10000, 0x0bc62ae0, 0x0bc62c00, 0x0bc86000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3301K [0x147c0000, 0x153c0000, 0x187c0000)
   the space 12288K,  26% used [0x147c0000, 0x14af9498, 0x14af9600, 0x153c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 65.631 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=252 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 14528K, used 13957K [0x047c0000, 0x05780000, 0x09d10000)
  eden space 12928K, 100% used [0x047c0000, 0x05460000, 0x05460000)
  from space 1600K,  64% used [0x05460000, 0x055616a8, 0x055f0000)
  to   space 1600K,   0% used [0x055f0000, 0x055f0000, 0x05780000)
 tenured generation   total 32216K, used 32074K [0x09d10000, 0x0bc86000, 0x147c0000)
   the space 32216K,  99% used [0x09d10000, 0x0bc62ae0, 0x0bc62c00, 0x0bc86000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3301K [0x147c0000, 0x153c0000, 0x187c0000)
   the space 12288K,  26% used [0x147c0000, 0x14af9498, 0x14af9600, 0x153c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 65.723 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=253 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 17856K, used 0K [0x047c0000, 0x05b10000, 0x09d10000)
  eden space 15936K,   0% used [0x047c0000, 0x047c0000, 0x05750000)
  from space 1920K,   0% used [0x05750000, 0x05750000, 0x05930000)
  to   space 1920K,   0% used [0x05930000, 0x05930000, 0x05b10000)
 tenured generation   total 39484K, used 23688K [0x09d10000, 0x0c39f000, 0x147c0000)
   the space 39484K,  59% used [0x09d10000, 0x0b4323e8, 0x0b432400, 0x0c39f000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 3299K [0x147c0000, 0x153c0000, 0x187c0000)
   the space 12288K,  26% used [0x147c0000, 0x14af8e78, 0x14af9000, 0x153c0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.870 Thread 0x00ddc400 Threw 0x04c01580 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.871 Thread 0x00ddc400 Threw 0x04c04f60 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.872 Thread 0x00ddc400 Threw 0x04c0a9c0 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.890 Thread 0x00ddc400 Threw 0x047c5b88 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.893 Thread 0x00ddc400 Threw 0x047d2aa8 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.895 Thread 0x00ddc400 Threw 0x047d7830 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.975 Thread 0x00ddc400 Threw 0x04b3a1a0 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.976 Thread 0x00ddc400 Threw 0x04b3d7d0 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.976 Thread 0x00ddc400 Threw 0x04b40a28 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 2.643 Thread 0x00ddc400 Threw 0x04b8a748 at C:\re\jdk7u45\229\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244

Events (10 events):
Event: 63.677 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
Event: 63.682 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done
Event: 64.108 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
Event: 64.113 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done
Event: 64.615 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
Event: 64.619 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done
Event: 65.202 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
Event: 65.207 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done
Event: 65.631 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation
Event: 65.723 Executing VM operation: GenCollectForAllocation done


Dynamic libraries:
0x01390000 - 0x013bf000     C:\Windows\jre\bin\javaw.exe
0x77c40000 - 0x77dc0000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x76dd0000 - 0x76ee0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x770e0000 - 0x77127000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x77350000 - 0x773f0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77180000 - 0x7722c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x767f0000 - 0x76809000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x75780000 - 0x75870000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x75670000 - 0x756d0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x75660000 - 0x7566c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x77550000 - 0x77650000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x756e0000 - 0x75770000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x767e0000 - 0x767ea000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x76f80000 - 0x7701d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x6e8b0000 - 0x6ea4e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x76ac0000 - 0x76b17000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x76810000 - 0x76870000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x773f0000 - 0x774bc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x62870000 - 0x6292f000     C:\Windows\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x57790000 - 0x57b10000     C:\Windows\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x75380000 - 0x75387000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x77140000 - 0x77175000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x77130000 - 0x77136000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x72f20000 - 0x72f52000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x75770000 - 0x75775000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x73ac0000 - 0x73acc000     C:\Windows\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x70f70000 - 0x70f90000     C:\Windows\jre\bin\java.dll
0x70eb0000 - 0x70ec3000     C:\Windows\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00320000 - 0x0036d000     C:\Users\juppso\Dropbox\Java\LWJGL\Lwjgl Game testing\Gametest\lib\natives-win\lwjgl.dll
0x5ece0000 - 0x5eda8000     C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll
0x67b80000 - 0x67ba2000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x5ebf0000 - 0x5ecd7000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x73820000 - 0x73826000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x75880000 - 0x75a1d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x76f40000 - 0x76f67000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
0x77050000 - 0x770df000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x75a20000 - 0x75b7c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x76970000 - 0x76982000     C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x6f070000 - 0x6f083000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x75590000 - 0x75599000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6f0c0000 - 0x6f140000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x6ed10000 - 0x6ef22000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\nView\nview.dll
0x75b90000 - 0x767da000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
0x71a10000 - 0x71a1d000     C:\Windows\system32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x6f140000 - 0x6f145000     C:\Windows\system32\MSIMG32.dll
0x6f090000 - 0x6f0b5000     C:\Windows\system32\POWRPROF.dll
0x754e0000 - 0x75501000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x768a0000 - 0x768e5000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WLDAP32.dll
0x6f210000 - 0x6f254000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\nView\NVWRSENU.dll
0x52ba0000 - 0x541b0000     C:\Windows\system32\nvoglv32.DLL
0x76d40000 - 0x76dc3000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x73260000 - 0x73267000     C:\Windows\system32\msiltcfg.dll
0x711e0000 - 0x71420000     C:\Windows\system32\msi.dll
0x70130000 - 0x70133000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SFC.DLL
0x70120000 - 0x7012d000     C:\Windows\system32\sfc_os.DLL
0x68ba0000 - 0x68c19000     C:\Windows\system32\mscms.dll
0x71a20000 - 0x71a37000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x75390000 - 0x7539b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x67cf0000 - 0x67d28000     C:\Windows\system32\icm32.dll
0x701e0000 - 0x701f4000     C:\Windows\jre\bin\net.dll
0x189c0000 - 0x18a0e000     C:\Windows\system32\pbproxy.dll
0x717d0000 - 0x7180c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSWSOCK.dll
0x717b0000 - 0x717cc000     C:\Windows\system32\iphlpapi.dll
0x717a0000 - 0x717a7000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x715c0000 - 0x715d4000     C:\Windows\system32\WTFastDrv.dll
0x711c0000 - 0x711c6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x73960000 - 0x7396f000     C:\Windows\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x56cb0000 - 0x56df3000     C:\Windows\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x701b0000 - 0x701c6000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x70140000 - 0x7017b000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x6fdc0000 - 0x6fdce000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x6f510000 - 0x6f56f000     C:\Windows\system32\SXS.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\juppso\Dropbox\Java\LWJGL\Lwjgl Game testing\Gametest\lib\natives-win -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: main.Main Xmx1G
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program files\java\jdk1.7.0_13
PATH=C:/Windows/system32/../jre/bin/client;C:/Windows/system32/../jre/bin;C:/Windows/system32/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Juppso Games Inc\New folder;
USERNAME=juppso
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 12 (6 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 45 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 16704980k(11030776k free), swap 33408096k(25659448k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.45-b08) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_45-b18), built on Oct  8 2013 06:02:43 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Mon Apr 28 12:58:13 2014
elapsed time: 65 seconds
```

It could also be the way I am using the object, I am creating the variable's to store the object inside a player entity-

```
private RenderFont ScoreTextRender;
private RenderFont HealthTextRender;
private RenderFont ShieldTextRender;
```

and then I do this on the update of the entity which runs everytime the game updates

```
ScoreTextRender.SetText("Score: "+this.Score);
HealthTextRender.SetText("Health: "+this.health);
ShieldTextRender.SetText("Sheild: "+this.sheild);
ScoreTextRender.Draw();
HealthTextRender.Draw();
ShieldTextRender.Draw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well I feel so dumb, It was simply a matter of a not closing the fileInputStream. Sigh what a beginners mistake, Ah well it al works now!!!